# Update/Delete Certificate chain: Cannot assign the key to the given alias

Tags: java, digital-signature, keystore, public-key-encryption, digital-certificate

I want to update my previous self-signed certificate with new one eg: **chains** which is returned (signed CSR) from TEST CA.  My default keystore is: *Windows-MY*

- Step 1: I have created  a private-public key pair, self-signed
  certifcate and CSR(private key is stored in Windows-MY with
  self-signed certificate).
- Step 2: sent CSR to CA.
- Step 3: CA returns a certificate chain for that public key.

Now I want to replace that self-signed certificate with the CA returned certificate. NB: I have the private key stored in my store.

```
Key privKey = keyStore.getKey(commonName, keyPass);
System.out.println("invalid private key :" + (privKey == null));

// keyStore.deleteEntry(commonName);
// keyStore.load(null, keyPass);

if (isPrivateKeyAvailable) {
    System.out.println("name:" + commonName + " is updatded");
    keyStore.setKeyEntry(commonName, privKey, keyPass, chains);
} else {
    System.out.println("name:" + commonName + " does not exist");
}
```

But I am getting these errors:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot assign the key to the
>   given alias.  at
>   sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:415)     at
>   sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore$MY.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:55)
>     at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(Unknown Source)   at
>   keygenerator.KeyInstaller.installCertificateInWindowsStore(KeyInstaller.java:284)
>     at keygenerator.KeyInstaller.doJob(KeyInstaller.java:167)   at
>   keygenerator.KeyGeneration.installCertificate(KeyGeneration.java:171)
>     at keygenerator.KeyGeneration.main(KeyGeneration.java:68)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows keystore (named `Windows-MY` from Java) is not directly writable. You need to pack the private key and the certificate chain returned by CA into a PKCS#12 file (.p12) and import it using The Windows import tool.

Comment: Thanks for your kind attention. Please check the update

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your update. The answer is the same: you can not programmatically modify a windows-my keystore entry. Of course you can add the certification chain to your own keystore and save it in p12 format to import it later in Windows

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and it serves my purpose. Thanks.